# Multiple initialization in golang

Tags: loops, for-loop, go

Following id the code snippet

```
package main

import "fmt"

var text []int64

func main() {

    for i, j := 0, 1; i < 4; i, j = i+1, j+1 {
        fmt.Println("Value of i, j:", i, j)
        fmt.Println(text[j])
    }

}
```

And it shows the following error;

```
Value of i, j: 0 1
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/cg/root/6063741/main.go:13 +0x268
exit status 2
```

I wanted to know how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Here is the java code that I am trying to convert to go;

```
long    text[]; 
int     num        = 1

text = new long[num];

for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            text[i] = 0;
        // do something
}
if (num > 1) {
            for (int i=0,j=1; i<numSubs; i++,j++) {
        // do something
        System.out.Println(text[i]
)
       }
}
```

Comment: `text` is a nil slice, so it doesn't contain any data. What is it you expected to see?

Comment: I am actually, trying to convert the following to go..

Comment: text = new long[text];
Var num = 4
                
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            text[I] = 0;
     if num > 1 {
  //above code
  }
 }

Comment: `text = new long[text]; ` wot?

Comment: text = new long[num];

Comment: sorry , that was a typo

Comment: @Priyanka: don't put code in the comments. Update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Please tell us what your goal is. We don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: and `num` is undefined at that point. Do you have a complete and working piece of java(I presume) code that we can work of?

Comment: The goal is to convert the above java code to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
>
> For a slice `a`, `a[x]` denotes the element of the slice `a` indexed by `x`.
>   The index `x` is in range if `0 <= x < len(a)`, otherwise it is out of
>   range.

---

The variables `i` and `j` are indexes for the slice `text`. They must always be within range: `0 <= i < len(text)` and `0 <= j < len(text)`. Since `i < j`, that simplifies to `0 <= i` and`j < len(text)`.

For your Go example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

var text []int64

func main() {
    for i, j := 0, 1; i < 4 && j < len(text); i, j = i+1, j+1 {
        fmt.Println("Value of i, j:", i, j)
        fmt.Println(text[j])
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/02r_VY9VMa5